# flask-sqlalchemy give empty result from database view

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have Model:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
db = SQLAlchemy()
class Graph(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'graph_view'
    group = Column(Unicode(250), primary_key=True)
    port_id1 = Column('portid1', Integer)
    port_id2 = Column('portid2', Integer)
    equipment_id1 = Column('equipmentid1', Integer)
    equipment_id2 = Column('equipmentid2', Integer)
```

where graph_view is database view. I am doing SELECT after connect:

```
    Graph.query.all()
```

and i'm getting nothing. Query is not wrong what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Check that your database actually *has data*? Are you using the return value of `Graph.query.all()`? What is your view code?

Comment: I have a different Model(which is a table not a view) and it works fine.

Comment: Also i get query from "print Graph.query" execute it and it works

Comment: What I mean is that we are *not* psychic (however much SO answerers sometimes may seem to be). If your query is not wrong and there are no results returned, then *your database is empty*.

Comment: Graph is not a table. Graph is a view('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW graph_view AS SELECT...'). There is a key i guess. Should it work anyway?

Comment: For SQLAlchemy there is no difference, it'll just execute the SQL query (what you see in `print Graph.query`). It is up to your database to return results for that.

Comment: "print Graph.query.all()" shows "[None]". I dont know why is it happens. "print Graph.query" shows query which executes required data, i told it already.

Comment: I got it. db.session.query(Graph.equipment_id1, Graph.equipment_id2) works good.